# How can you programmatically change which xaml page is opened on launch?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm working on an app that has a login screen, which then goes to the apps actual content pages. After they've logged in once successfully, I'd like to make it so when they open the app, it automatically goes to the main content page. Right now, i have it so it loads the login page, then pulls the login info from isolatedstorage, and logs in again. But it'd be even better if I could just open up to the content page right away, so they don't even have to see the login page. Is there a way to do this? If I had the ability to programmatically change which page the app lands on first that would be amazing.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Apparently there is a way! How do I do it?

Comment: To literally answer your question: Yes, there is a way to do this. :)

Comment: I also updated the question :P

Comment: Yes there is. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664673/how-to-show-different-pages-when-app-launches-time-in-windows-phone-7/9664863

Comment: Awesome, that's it then. thank you very much, if you post that as an answer I'll accept it real quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what I ended up doing: [How to show different pages when app launches time in windows phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664673/how-to-show-different-pages-when-app-launches-time-in-windows-phone-7/9664863) thanks to Willem

works like a charm, I just have to check my IsolatedStorageSettings in my app.cs and then make the appropriate descision based on that.